# How do I limit TextView to full lines

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a cell in a ListView with the following layout.

[image: Cell Layout]

The problem is the last line in the TextView with black text. I'd like to have only complete lines in that TextView (so two lines in this case), preferably with ellipsize to show that the text has been cut off.

In this specific instance, I could just set maxLines="2", but sometimes the pink title might only be a single line, so in those cases I'd like the body to have the full three lines that there would be room for.

Edit: Showing XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgNews"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:src="@drawable/news1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgNews"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">    

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblNewsDate"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#b3b3b3b3"
                android:maxLines="1"
                tools:text="29. oktober 2015" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblNewsTitle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="#df0784"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                tools:text="Festivalen modtager donationer fra fionia fond"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblNewsDescription"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                tools:text="H.C. Andersen Festivals åbner nu for ansøgninger om projekter til festivalen i 2016. Festivalen leder blandt andet efter gadegøgl, teater, dans, musik, foredrag, installationer og kunst, som kan være med til at skabe et forunderligt og overraskende univers i uge 34 i Odense."/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Show the adapters layout which you are using

Answer (score 3):

If you know you always will be able to show two lines (it depends on how your layout adapts itself) you can set max number of lines to two, and you can set the ellipsize too in order to trim your String and put "..." after cutting your message.

In your xml, in the Textview field:

```
android:maxLines = "2"
android:ellipsize = "end"
```

Suggestion: Why don't you use two different Textviews? One for title and other for content.

Comment: I know that I can use maxLines and ellipsize. The problem is that there is sometimes room for three lines. And when there is that, I'd like to show three lines.

Comment: Can you show us your xml layout? It would be faster!!

Comment: Absolute height (like 110dp) are the thing. I don't know if you worth to deal with absolute dimensions (obviously it depends on your project and desing). I always try to work with wrap_content or match_parent and, not less important, weights (for LinearLayouts). wrap_content will adapt the container to your content. If you set your containers with wrap_content, you center your LinearLayout and you set maxLines to 3, the gap difference between two or three lines  to the container should be appropriate. This is my advise analysing your code without changing so much... I hope this would help

Comment: Unfortunately, the design does demand that the cells be of equal height. My current solution is to use maxLines="2" with a fixed cell height. It doesn't look bad, but I would like it if I could get the view to be perfect.

Comment: oh, ok. Design rules haha. Sorry if I was not able to help you at all.